# Application of Implicit Function Theorem to the triangle

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Well, I observe the triangle with side-lengths $a, b, c$ and angle $\alpha$, the opposite angle to $a$. The implicit relationship between them should be The Law of Cosines : $a^2-b^2-c^2+2bc\cos \alpha=0$

Then if I write $\alpha$ as smooth function of $a, b, c$, namely
$\alpha=\arccos \frac{c^2+b^2-a^2}{2bc} = f(a,b,c)$, under what circumstances I can do that? This problem should be related to the Implicit Function Theorem. Of course, we must have $b,c\neq0$. Does that mean that $\alpha$ can be written as a smooth function of $a, b, c$ everywhere except in the neighbourhood of $(k,0,0)$, when we look from the point of IFT, or under another circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $F(a,b,c,\alpha) = a^2-b^2-c^2+2bc\cos\alpha$. Then $\alpha$ is defined implicitly as a function of $a,b,c$ by the equation $F(a,b,c,\alpha) = 0$. Examining carefully the statement of the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), given $(a_0,b_0,c_0,\alpha_0)$ which satisfy the Law of Cosines, we may write $\alpha = f(a,b,c)$ (in such a way that $F(a,b,c, f(a,b,c)) = 0$) in a neighborhood of $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$ when $F_\alpha(a_0,b_0,c_0,\alpha_0)\neq 0$.

Since $F_\alpha = -2bc\sin\alpha$, we need $b,c\neq 0$ and $\alpha\neq 0$. In other words, we need $b,c>0$ and the triangle to not be degenerating (implying $a>0$ as well). So we are guaranteed invertibility so long as we can draw a valid triangle with positive side lengths $a,b,c$.

Comment: Here $F_{\alpha}$ denotes derivative of F with respect to $\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Since $F:\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R$, the Jacobian minor that you look at for the Implicit Function Theorem is just the $1\times 1$ matrix $F_\alpha$. One can also show that $\partial \alpha/\partial x = -F_x/F_\alpha$ where $x\in\{a,b,c\}$ in this case.

Of course, this is all from the viewpoint of some pretty sophisticated machinery. One can directly check that $-1\leq (c^2+b^2-a^2)/(2bc)\leq 1$ and so $\alpha$ can always be obtained by taking $\arccos$ (there was another answer that mentioned this, but it seems to have been deleted for whatever reason).